# Capture a single value in Razor Page from Model, I get an error? How do I change this to a Razor Page style variable?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, razor-pages

Here is my model and View info to capture a single value in a Razor page into a variable.

I get this error when trying to use this `IEnumerable`, but before with without `IEnumerable`, this worked without any errors.

Here is my program that works fine without `IEnumerable`, but how do you access all the tables that have relations together this way?:
[GlobalCommandCenter](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DP9vY4RdS9LcJJWqDt6G-DtRgKsEnOo2/view)

```
View showing Model connection using IEnumerable:
@model  IEnumerable<OperationsCommandCenter.Models.CommandCenterModel>
```

Error in view that I am getting with `IEnumerable` in Razor page:

[image: Error In View]

Model:

```
using ClassLibraryDAL.DAL;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace OperationsCommandCenter.Models
{
    public class CommandCenterModel
    {
        public List<DimLocation> LocationDatas { get; set; }
        public List<DimLocation> DimLocations { get; set; }

        public List<DimProductInventory> DimProducts { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Country { get; set; } 
        public List<SelectListItem> Continent { get; set; } 

        public List<SelectListItem> Product { get; set; } 
        public List<SelectListItem> FactInventory { get; set; } 
        public List<SelectListItem> query { get; set; }                                              
        public string SectionCity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can not convert a list to a string. Try firstordefault() then tostring(). Do not forget to add namespace System.Linq

Comment: Please do not use image links in your question.